# Since when I've been following a user on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, follow

Is there a way to find out how long I've been following a specific user on Twitter? There is no info about that on my following list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked the API Documentation and there is no mention of being able to retrieve the date that you started following someone. Unless Twitter make this information available on user profiles or add it to the API it doesn't appear to be available.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for checking the API documentation, Barry. I thought it could be possible, but no big deal.